# Sending Signed XML to secure WebService returns BadSignature

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-7

I am using Delphi 7's `HTTPReqResp` component to send a digitally signed SOAP XML Document to a HTTPS web service. I use Eldos XML BlackBox and have set all the `transformAlgorithms`, `CanonicalizationMethod`, `signaturemethod`, etc. to the ones the web service requires and have confirmed this with a tech support officer.

I have validated the signature using XML BlackBox and also this [XML Verifier website](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/xmldsig-verifier.html).

Both ways confirm the signature is correct. However, when I send the XML document via `HTTPReqResp.execute`, the response I get back is `BadSignature (The signature value is invalid)`.

Originally, I received back a different error messages due to XML errors (malformed, etc.). It appears that the service will do all the standard formatting checks first, then it will attempt to validate the signature. Since I get back the `BadSignature` response, the rest of the XML must be correct.

I suppose I have 2 questions here.

1. Does the HTTPReqResp component alter the XML.
2. Is it likely the webservice alters the XML.

The site is using Access Manager WebSEAL.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the receiving partner is getting a modified document somehow. Some minor modifications shouldn't affect the signature (that's the idea, at least) so you may want to check the following:

1. "Recommended" encoding used by the receiving partner. A very annoying practice by some receiving partners is to favor one form of encoding and completely ignore others. XML signatures should use `utf-8` but I've seen servers that only accept `iso-8859-1`
2. Make sure  you don't accidentally change encoding after signing.
3. Verify that the receiving partner is using a sane canonicalization method.
4. Verify with your receiving partner that no extraneous elements are being added to your document.

Also, have you tried to post this using the SecureBlackBox components? They also have an HTTP client that can do SSL, and that can be used to also verify the bytes being sent through the wire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My XML uses utf-8. Since the document is signed and saved to disk, then that file is verified OK, I assume the encoding has not changed after signing. Re the SecureBlackBox components, which component or components should I be looking at? The file goes to a web address (URL).

Comment: Take a look at the `HTTPBlackBox` package, specifically the `TElHTTPSClient` component.

Comment: I have that component, just not sure how to use it. I have set OnCertificateNeeded and supplied the X509 Certificate, and have called the Post method with a url and a stream representing my XML. It also has OnCertificateValidate which I set to true. I have also set the OutPutStream. When I then run the POST method, it just sits there and the program is unresponsive. Obviously not using it correctly. Can you please point me in the right directions. Thank you

Comment: This problem has been resolved. Turns out the webservice was particular about receiving too much information with the signature element. I removed any of the RSA signing, etc elements and el presto it worked. Thanks......